# KeyError when python files executing in django application

Tags: django, django-views, python-2.7

```
TypeError at /python_tutor
'instancemethod' object is not subscriptable
```

when i run this script in online python tutor script :

```
def tutor(request):
    print "Inisde tutor", request.method
    print "POST =", request.POST

    if request.method == "POST" :
        print "Inside Post"
        print "My Script =", request.POST["user_script"]
        mycode = request.POST.get["user_script",none]
        exec mycode
```

**NameError at /python_tutor
name 'none' is not defined**

Comment: Seriously, you're executing random code that your users are uploading? You'd better hope none of them upload `import os; os.system('rm -rf /')`.

Comment: @DanielRoseman You know that wouldn't be executed :)

Answer (score 4):

Try changing `none` to `None`.
Capitalization matters. Also, it looks like there should be round brackets instead of square brackets after `get`.

Comment: Thanking for your help. its worked. but i want to display output on on same page. it gives at terminal ....

Comment: That's quite a separate thing. I suggest you move further through the tutorial you're working with (did I get it right?). When you learn how Django generates pages, you're welcome to come back and ask questions, if any :)

Comment: I know how to generate pages. https://github.com/pgbovine/OnlinePythonTutor/ . In this link : cgi-bin/web_exec.py / please go through that and help me. ho w can i call that web-exec.py in my django application views.py .

Comment: my views.py code is :  from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, render_to_response
from django.template import RequestContext
import os

def tutor(request):
 print "Inisde tutor", request.method
 print "POST =", request.POST
   
 if request.method == "POST" :
  print "Inside Post"
  print "My Script =", request.POST["user_script"]
  mycode = request.POST.get("user_script",None)
         exec mycode
       
 return render_to_response('tutor.html', context_instance=RequestContext(request))

Comment: You need to pass everything you want to display to `render_to_response` in the 'context'. I'd really suggest creating a new question for Django experts to see it and help.